# Loft insulation

Tags: insulation, attic

I want to add loft insulation. The joists have 400mm gaps between and are 75mm high. There is no product which precisely matches this which I can find. Some have suggested adding 25mm battens to the joists but that seems like a huge faff.

1. If I fill between with 100mm and then add another layer over the top, this will leave a 25mm gap above the joists. Is this an issue? (Very good ventilation in the loft space, btw)
2. Would it be better to use batts for the lower layer if I did this, as they're a bit stiffer. (Though I imagine a layer of loft roll would not be so heavy as to significantly compress the lower layer anyway.)
3. Another option would be 50mm batts and then a breathable foil layer above stapled to the joists. e.g. TXL Gold or Breatherquilt. I know these are usually used at roof level, but I don't see why they wouldn't work in an even better ventilated location. Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Dead air acts as a good insulation layer. I wouldn't think that the 25mm (1") gap at the top of each joist (filled with non-moving air) is going to significantly impact your insulation capacity. If anything, it will _very slightly_ increase the insulation capacity.

Comment: Have you looked into loose-fill [you pour it yourself from bags] or blown fibre [an installer blows it for you with a big machine & pipe]? Both will fill any space to any depth. Quick précis of insulation types - https://www.which.co.uk/reviews/insulation/article/how-to-buy-loft-insulation/installing-blanket-insulation-aO9nV9S6rjBF